# В функции не работает округление и работа с файлами

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

У меня такая проблема - пишу программу C++/CLI, VS 2010, WinForms.

Открыл функцию кнопки в Form1.h, хочу внутри нее (кнопки) сделать процедуру округления своего вычисления, открыть файл и записать в него результат - не получается. Не знаю, куда включить заголовочные файлы `include <fstream>` и `include <math.h>`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать?

Вот часть кода кнопки:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    double a,b,c,d;
    double p1,p2,p3,P,Pa,Pb,Pc;

    ofstream file;
    file.open("D:\\text.dat");

    d = Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Text);
    a = Convert::ToDouble(textBox3->Text);
    b = Convert::ToDouble(textBox4->Text);
    c = Convert::ToDouble(textBox5->Text);                   

    p1=a/d;
    p2=b/d;
    p3=c/d;
    P=(p1+p2+p3)/3;
    Pa=p1/3/P*100;
    Pa=ceil(Pa);
```

Вот ошибки:

> c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\456\456\Form1.h(190): error C3861: ceil: идентификатор не найден
>   1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\456\456\Form1.h(206): error C2065: file: необъявленный идентификатор
>   1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\456\456\Form1.h(206): error C2228: выражение слева от ".close" должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение
>   1>          тип: 'unknown-type'

Comment: C++ и C++/CLI - это два _разных_ языка. В WinForms вы используете именно C++/CLI - так называемый managed (управляемый) диалект. В принципе, можно смешивать оба языка в коде. Но проще использовать какой-то один - будет меньше путаницы и проблем с приведениями типов.

Comment: Для работы с файлами используйте типы из пространства имён [System.IO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io?view=netframework-4.7).

Comment: Для округления и тому подобных операций используйте методы класса [Math](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math?view=netframework-4.7)